# How to overload the ostream operator for 3D vector?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

How to overload the stream extraction operator for a three dimensional vector?

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> V(5, vector<int>>(3, vector<int>(2)))
```

I came up with the following response. Why isn't the following code correct?

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, vector<T> &V) {
    for(int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < V[i].size(); j++) 
            output << V[i][j] << " ";
    return output;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Missing return statement is one problem with your code. Missing description of your problem is one problem with your question.

Comment: what is a `Vector`? (capital V)

Comment: @RichardHodges A wild guess says that it's `template<typename T> using Vector = vector<vector<vector<T>>>;` ;) Or that's what it should probably be.

Comment: @vsoftco assuming that's the case I have posted a universal vector print as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit condition on your `j` loop is incorrect, you need `j < V[i].size()`.

You say your vector has three dimensions but your are only looping over two dimensions.

It is not clear exactly what type you are passing into your stream operator but I assume it is something like `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>` and as you are not modifying it you should pass it by const reference.

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
using Vector = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>;

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Vector<T>& v) {
  for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++) {
      for(size_t k = 0; k < v[i][j].size(); k++)
        output << v[i][j][k] << " ";
      output << "\n";
    }
    output << "\n";
  }
  return output;
}
```

Or in C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Vector<T>& v) {
  for(const auto& layer : v) {
    for(const auto& row : layer) {
      copy(row.begin(), row.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(output, " "));
      output << "\n";
    }
    output << "\n";
  }
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, a general remark: It is in general **not a good idea** to represent a 3D vector as a vector of vectors of vectors *in any language*. Please do not propagate this antipattern.

The right way of storing multidimensional vectors is to keep them "flattened" in a 1D vector. 2D example using row major order:

this is your 2D vector/array:

```
00 01 02
10 11 12
```

you would store it in row-major order as:

```
00 01 02 10 11 12
```

and index the elements accordingly. The `[i][j]`-th element is at `[i*colno +j]` in the flat 1D array, where `colno` is the number of columns. Note, however, that if you need "ragged arrays", i.e. where the last dimension contains rows of unequal size, then some more thinking is required.

Second, you should rather use appropriate libraries to work with such multidimensional arrays/vectors. There are lots of those, you can check out e.g. [the Eigen matrix library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org), which incidentally provides an overloaded `<<` operator for simple output :-).

Third, your code is iterating over 2 dimensions only, and is not passing the "vector-of-vectors-of-vector" argument correctly, as others already pointed out. Also for the future: pass objects as const reference to a function that is not going to modify those objects, like `V` in your example. And return the `ostream` object once you are done with the output.

But overall, and please take no offense: you need to attend a **good programming course**. Programming is difficult, programming in C++ is even more difficult. One needs all the help one can get. Believe me, I know what I am talking about... :-)

Answer (score 2):

it took me a little while to come up with a universal solution, but here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template <typename T, typename _ = void>
struct is_vector : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct is_vector< T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,std::vector< typename T::value_type,typename T::allocator_type >>::value
>::type>
: std::true_type
{
};

template<class T>
auto
emit(std::ostream& os, const T& t, size_t indent = 0)
-> std::enable_if_t<!is_vector<T>::value>
{
    os << std::string(indent, ' ') << t;
}

template<class T, class A>
auto
emit(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T, A>& v, size_t indent = 0)
-> std::enable_if_t<!is_vector<T>::value>
{
    std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ') << "{ ";
    const char* sep = "";
    for (const auto& i : v) {
        os << sep;
        emit(os, i);
        sep = ", ";
    }
    os << " }";
}

template<class T, class A>
auto
emit(std::ostream&os, const std::vector<T, A>& v, size_t indent = 0)
-> std::enable_if_t<is_vector<T>::value, void>
{
    const auto prefix = std::string(indent, ' ');

    std::cout << prefix << "{\n";
    const char* sep = "";
    for (const auto& i : v) {
        os << sep;
        emit(os, i, indent + 2);
        sep = ",\n";
    }
    os << "\n" << prefix << "}";
}

template<class T, class A>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, const std::vector<T, A>& v)
{
    emit(os, v);
    return os;
}


using VI = std::vector<int>;
using VVI = std::vector<VI>;
using VVVI = std::vector<VVI>;

    using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto vi = VI { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    cout << "\n1 dimension:\n";
    cout << vi << endl;

    auto vvi = VVI {
        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
        {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 },
    };
    cout << "\n2 dimensions:\n";
    cout << vvi << endl;

    auto vvvi = VVVI {
        {
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
            {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 },
        },
        {
            {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 },
            {30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 },
        }
    };
    cout << "\n3 dimensions:\n";
    cout << vvvi << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
1 dimension:
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }

2 dimensions:
{
  { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
  { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 }
}

3 dimensions:
{
  {
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
    { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 }
  },
  {
    { 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 },
    { 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 }
  }
}
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: This is some nice way of doing it!